# Why do I get error when use keras Conv2D layer?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, keras

I use the next keras based architecture ([article](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/0830affa1f7f19fd47b06d4cf89ed44d)):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
...
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

model.save_weights('first_try.h5')

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img

img = load_img('test_data/a1.jpg')  # this is a PIL image
img = img.resize((150, 150))
x = img_to_array(img)

prediction = model.predict(x)
print(prediction)
```

ValueError: Error when checking : expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (150, 150, 3)

Can you please advise how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are feeding a single sample to the model, which instead expects a batch of samples, that is where the 4 expected dimensions come from: batch_size + img_shape.

One of many ways to get what you want for single image is

```
x = np.array([img])
```

Comment: also I have found x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

Comment: @OlegDats exactly, and even a simple `x.reshape(1, *img.shape)` should work.